# How to check if JTextField equals certain value in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, equality

I'm trying to make a program where the user pick the operation and then tow random numbers will appear in `JTextField`, and user should put the answer in another text field, I'm trying to check weather the result equals the answer text field or not and then display false or correct in a text field. But it always display "false".

Here's my method:

```
public cal() {
        initComponents();
    }
  Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);  
double result, ans,ad;
String opr; 

double num1= ((int)(Math.random()*100));
String str1= Double.toString(num1);
double num2= ((int)(Math.random()*100));
String str2= Double.toString(num2);
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void initComponents() {

        jFrame1 = new javax.swing.JFrame();
        jLayeredPane1 = new javax.swing.JLayeredPane();
        jSeparator1 = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        adbut = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        subbut = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        divbut = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        mulbut = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        opersign = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        n1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        n2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        answer = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        checkbut = new javax.swing.JButton();
        dis = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void adbutActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        opersign.setText("+");
        opr="+";
        n1.setText(str1);
        n2.setText(str2);
    }                                     

    private void subbutActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        opersign.setText("-");    
        opr="-"; 
        n1.setText(str1);
        n2.setText(str2);
    }                                      

    private void divbutActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        opersign.setText("/");
        opr="/";
        n1.setText(str1);
        n2.setText(str2);
    }                                      

    private void mulbutActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        opersign.setText("*");
        opr="*";
        n1.setText(str1);
        n2.setText(str2);
    }                                      

    private void disActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {      
    }                                   

    private void n1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {        
    }                                  
    
    private void opersignActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    }                                        

    private void n2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {        
    }                                  

    private void answerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
         
         ans= Double.parseDouble(answer.getText());
    }                                      

    private void checkbutActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        if(opr=="+") result= num1+num2;
        else if(opr=="-") result= num1-num2;
        else if(opr=="/") result= num1/num2;
        else result= num1 * num2;

        if(result != ans) dis.setText(" FALSE ");
        else if (result == ans) dis.setText(" CORRECT!! ");
    }
```

Comment: So you said TWICE now that you want to compare the CONTENT of the first JTextField with the other JTextField ITSELF (comparing a string to a Control). What surely actually mean is that you wanna compare the content/string of the first with the content/string of the second. Please fix that in your answer. The solution, if we have the `String result` and textFiel2, would be: `Objects.equals(result, textField2.getText())`. One could also write `result.equals(textField2.getText())`, but if somehow the the `result == null` (you could set that manually) then the second example would fail.

Comment: 1) This has nothing to do with the IDE, don't mention or tag it. OTOH it has a lot to do with Swing, so tag that. 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Comment: It's hard to tell from just the context here, as this program is not actually runnable.  One issue that may or may not be causing problems is using reference equality on strings (e.g. `opr=="+"`).  `opr` might be "+", but a different object, so this could be messing it up and always doing the final else (multiplication).